# how to include files in D source code, just as it is done in C

Tags: include, d

that is:

```
#include "mySnippet.h"
```

Does D even have such thing ?

Using `import "myInclude.d"` procuces:

```
test.d(5): Error: Identifier expected following import
test.d(5): Error: ';' expected
```

Comment: @MaciejHehl: I am lazy indeed. *Larry, being the lazy programmer that he is...* http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/lperl/ch01_02.htm

Comment: Well in that case the answer for you is: You can't do it ("include files in D source code, just as it is done in C") because it's a different language. I hope your approach is working well for you :)

Comment: @MaciejHehl: Yes we can, look the most upvoted comment here.

Comment: Why don't you just read a tutorial, any tutorial? What's next week, "can I add two numbers in D, like in C"?

Comment: @FeepingCreature: D is very similar to C and C++ so it's nothing unusual asking for same features.

Comment: Well, if you spent few minutes of your time going through http://dlang.org/language-reference.html , you would probably know the answer to your question. I believe that is why FeepingCreature reacts as he does... ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing that is remotely similar to the C/C++ #include statement is the in-place import of a file, and then mixing that into the source:

```
mixin(import("mySnippet.d"));
```

D is a [modular programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) and the `import` statement is your friend when you do D programming.

In D you really do not need anything like `#pragma once`. This extension, and include-guards are there because C and C++ do not care about these things. D does.

However, I assume you are probably wondering how you give the interface to your clients in case you create a library and you do not want to expose the internals. For this purpose the DPL team came up with the [D interface files](http://dlang.org/dmd-linux.html#interface_files) in order to solve this problem. So, you simply give the interface files to your client along with your library, and job is done.

Answer (score 5):

See the reference file at: http://dlang.org/module.html

The imports are done like this (extracted from there):

```
import std.stdio; // import module stdio from package std
import foo, bar; // import modules foo and bar

void main() {
  writefln("hello!\n"); // calls std.stdio.writefln
}
```

And modules are created like this:

```
module A;
void foo();
void bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

The D style is:

```
import myinclude;
```

D doesn't have a textual include like C.

Comment: Well, it kinda does - you can use `mixin(import("foo.d"));` for textual include. Of course you shouldn't really do this, but still!

Comment: You can't actually `#include char_array` in C, so actually this is more powerful. More like Python's `__import__()` builtin.

Comment: @Robert: can it have a `#pragma once` statement like c++ ?

Comment: @rsk82 why would you need to use textual include at all?

Answer (score 0):

D doesn't include files in the same way as C/C++.

C/C++ actually copies the contents of the included file at the location of the #include, which is why the '#pragma once' or other inclusion guard is required, because the code will really be copied for each time it is in a #include line.

D doesn't bother with copying the source around, and compiles each source file into its own object file. The 'import' command in D asks for the symbols (or the names of each function, class, struct, enum, and variable) found in the module that is asked for. The compiler then just has to connect these object files together into the executable. Well, there's a bit more to it than that, but that should be accurate enough for this.

Also, as Mr Ruppe said, there is no need to enclose the name of the source file in quotes, nor do you need to add the file extension to the name.

If, for example, you have your main() function in main.d, and you want to include a source file called foo.d, that is in the same folder as main.d, then you type the following into main.d;

```
import foo;
```

and in foo, you would have;

```
module foo;
<other code here>
```

Hope this helps. Most of this is also on http://dlang.org, on their ['modules'](http://dlang.org/module.html#ImportDeclaration) page under the language definitions.